# WCF net.tcp service enabled ports are accessible if Silverlight application is browsed using HTTP but inaccessible from HTTPS

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, tcp, https

I have a WCF Service hosted as a Windows Service in the server.
The endpoint is net.tcp endpoint. We are accessing the endpoints from a Silverlight application.

Problem is when we are trying to access the service from the web app while browsing the Silverlight application using HTTP it works fine. But when we try to do so removing HTTP binding from the Silverlight app from IIS and browse the app using HTTPS the service endpoints are unavailable and gets access permission error from Sockets. I am attaching the error screenshot below:

> Could not connect to service. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0865926. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way while the service is not configured for cross-domain access. You may need to contact the owner of the service to expose a sockets cross-domain policy over HTTP and host the service in the allowed sockets port range.

Comment: Https is secure while http is not secure.  You may have a cookie that was using http that is causing an issue.  So I would first try from your IE history to manually remove all cookies and then try again.  If you still have an issue then I recommend attempting to connect using an IE.  You may need a certificate to connect and the IE will give more info on the location of the certificate.  If you can connect using an IE then I would use a sniffer and compare the http headers using IE with your application and see the differences.

Comment: @jdweng ... the issued is when I keep both the application binding http and https in iis for the app and I login using http and https I can connect to the service  endpoint... But if I remove the http binding from the app and try to browse with https cleaning all the browser cache then I can't get to the endpoint....

I am not understanding about the certificate issue that you are mentioning.. Do I have to add some configuration change in the WCF service...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I don't know.  HTTPS is secure and usually requires a certificate.  That is why I asked you to do certain steps to isolate issue.